# Regexp in php, take html

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

i need help. I have HTML, and i need regular expression which give me table. only one table. because after this table goes another tables.
example html:

```
<table class="results" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="left">
    <tr><td>text</td></tr>
</table>
<!-style>
tr.bg_selected{}
tr.bg_selected td, tr.bg_checked td { background-color:#ffe9bc !important;}
</style>**AND ANOTHER TABLE**
```

its my regular. there i get all tables after this table.

```
$regular = "/<table class=\"results\" cellspacing=\"(\d+)\" cellpadding=\"(\d+)\" border=\"(\d+)\" (.*)>(.*)<\/table>\n(.*)<\/style>/s";
    preg_match_all($regular,$str, $matches2, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: Please, read this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: [The Pony, He Comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1338999) *HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions.*

Comment: @OcuS can you repeat that comment in a more constructive manner?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, I can: don't use double-quotes in PHP ; it is getting evaluated by PHP to find if some variables are hidding in the string and theorically slows down the script execution. (But i'm still p*ssed off :)

Comment: @OcuS - Don't use execution speed as the reason to use single quotes over double quotes. The speed difference is not significant. Having said that, the example in the question would have been a lot more readable if he had used single quotes to avoid having to escape the quotes in the string. And that's the real point here: code readability is important. Readability (and thus maintainability) should trump optimisation every time (well, almost every time, anyway).

Comment: @SDC: That's why I wrote "theorically slows down".

Answer (score 1):

Some people have pointed out in the comments that you "can't parse HTML in regex". This isn't entirely accurate; it can be done.

However, it's difficult and error prone, and at the end of it you get a bit of a messy structure to work with.

I would therefore strongly recommend using PHP's built in HTML parser instead. It's very simple to use:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlCode);
```

You can then work with the resulting object to extract the data you need.

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach ($tables as $table){
    $cells = $table->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($cells as $cell){
        echo $cell->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

See the PHP manual for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Always use DOM ! Perfect answer.

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian - well, maybe not *always*, but certainly in anything but the most trivial case.